# How do I extract the value from a string using Regex

Tags: c++, regex, string

I'm trying to extract the number 9 from following string using regex;

" john ?\n\r\n\rFRED: 9"

My regex is

" john \?[\n\r]+FRED: (.*)"

The \n and \r are newline and return characters (white space) and bbviously "(.*) is the capturing group.

Its not working though! I'm guessing because of something really obvious.

By the way I know the obvious way to do this is to just search the string for the ":" and then get the number that way but I'm learning regex and I've spent quite a bit of time on this and it would be good
to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, please paste your [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the usage of your regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly escape control characters inside your regex.
`[\n\r]` in `john \?[\n\r]+FRED: (.*)` is matching `newline` and `carriage return`. Probably what you want is `\\r\\n`, so you can match it in the string.

The correct regex should be: `john \?[\\n\\r]+FRED: (.*)`

This is a great tool where you can visualize regex: https://regex101.com/r/qaRy5Z/1/

EDIT:
After comment suggestion, you can also use raw string literal so you can omit double backslashing:

```
 std::regex re(R"( john \?[\n\r]+FRED: (.*))");
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/U2AbTb

Comment: Using raw string literals for regular expressions makes the backslashes a lot easier to manage, btw - no escaping needed.